# Wifi drops and unable to reconnect RTL8821ae ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, ralink

I have an Asus F555L with the RTL8821ae wireless card. My wifi continually drops even within feet of of the router and attempting to reconnect fails. A different laptop, also running ubuntu 16.04 does not exhibit this problem. Our roku and phones are not experiencing these issues either.

None of the following commands seem to help:

```
rfkill block wifi
rfkill unblock wifi
sudo network-manager restart
```

Only rebooting seems to work, and then, only temporarily.

I'm currently using the rtl8821ae driver from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new).

[Here is the output from the wireless-info script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24876851).

Any thoughts?

Comment: what steps did you do to install new drivers? did you remove ad pergethe old ones?

Comment: I followed the steps here: https://medium.com/@elmaxx/rtl8821ae-wifi-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-04-4c1286524afa

I did not remove any drivers

Comment: ok the driver you downloaded (rtlwifi_new). usually fix most problems. purge the wifi drivers you have installed, then try to install the new

Answer (score 0):

Try a Network-Manager CON bounce.
ex:

```
sudo nmcli con down <Wireless_Con_Name_NOT_ID>
sudo nmcli con up <Wireless_Con_Name_NOT_ID>
```

run "nmcli con" (no sudo needed) to get the connection name from the first column.

... I do this with my VPN on a Cron schedule and it works like a charm. Particularly because if my LAN connection is set to "always use VPN" in Network-Manager it doesn't work properly at all. So I've even got a startup script for the VPN to auto-start 10-seconds after reboot. Which solved all my headaches. It's a bug, and a known one with Network-Manager. It used to work, but recently I changed VPN providers and on reboot I'd be left without internet every time. In-fact, that might've been your problem if you are like me and have a need for an always on VPN on your machine. Do NOT use the "Always use VPN" feature and just delay the startup script to kick on the VPN. In fact, here's my rc.local script for it:

added to /etc/rc.local, before the exit:

```
# call VPN delayed startup script    
sh -e /home/.apps/VPN-Delayed-Launch.sh
```

file contents in : /home/.apps/VPN-Delayed-Launch.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#Script to automatically connect to VPN
sleep 10; nmcli con up <VPN_Name_NOT_ID>
```

Comment: I'm not using a VPN. Also it's not merely after resuming from a suspend. It often drops while actively online.